# Copied files from mac partition to /root. But the /-partition is still full?

Tags: nautilus, root, macbook, clipboard, gksu

Help! Using `gksu-nautilus` I managed to look at files on my Mac partition via as simple right-click. However, at first journaling was still enabled on the Mac partition. Therefore any copied file would not be copied to where I wanted, but **only to the /root directory**.

I've noticed that my **/**-partition is full now. Therefore I went into **/root** and deleted the copied files (moved them to trash, *no* terminal). But gparted shows me that the */*-partition is still full?!!

(In Ubuntu I only have the **/**-partition, **/home**-partition and **swap**.)

Comment: so you moved files probably from /root to /root/.local/share/Trash ? That should be on the same partition. Maybe you want to move them to a different partition like /home ?

Comment: Trash is a part of /, so isn't it normal that your / partition is still full? I don't get the question. Can't you just remove the files and copy where you want to do?

Comment: Thank you guys! Both of you got the question right. I moved the files from /root to the trash. I also emptied the trash via the GUI. However, as you assumed correctly, when going to /root/.local/share/Trash via the terminal the files were still there!

Comment: loop trash is bad trash! :D

Comment: @Matt Instead of editing the title to solved, it helps if you ask one of the people who helped you to answer the question, then mark that answer as correct. Until then, this question will be marked unsanswered. You could also answer it yourself with the steps you took, and then mark that as correct.

Comment: @root45 Ok. I'm still fairly new to all of this... :-)

Comment: @xubuntix Would you mind answering the question, so that I can mark it as solved?

Comment: I cant mark as solved. I have added an answer that you can then mark as solving the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you moved files probably from `/root` to `/root/.local/share/Trash` 
That should be on the same partition. You want to move them to a different partition like e.g. `/home`